# Going Back to MainActivity from Child Activity in Android

Tags: android

In My Android app the flow looks like this: Main Page -> Page1 -> page2 -> page3. In Page1, Page2 & Page3 am having Home button, when clicked on Home button, It should launch Main Page(MainActivity). Here MainActivity Class gets the JSON Data from the server.

Now my question is: when am in Page1, Page2 Or Page3, if i click on Home button it should go to MainACtivity.At the same time, When Am in Page2, if i click device back button it should go to Page1. Simillarly, If am on page3, If i click on device back button it should go to page2.

For this, The usual solution i have used like,

```
//In Page1 Activity, Under Home button OnClickListner:
Intent in = new Intent(Page1.this,MainActivity.Class);
StartActivity(in);
```

With this, Everytime the MainActivity Class gets load & Communicates with Server, that results   low performance in app.

Another Approach i tried i.e,

```
//In Page1 Activity, Under Home button OnClickListner
finish();
```

This works fine for page1. If i use the finish() in the Page2, it launches the page1 activity. Alternatively i have used somewhat like this:

```
//In Page1 Activity:
Intent in = new Intent(Page1.this,Page2.Class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

And, in Page2, under Home Button OnClickListener i have written finish(). With this, when am in Page2 if i click on Home button, it will launch the MainActivity. At the same time if i click back button of device, it is launching MainActivity. It has to go to Page1.

Please, Can someone suggest me what i need to use for this suitation.

Thank you All.

Answer (score 5):

You should set a flag in your intent in the child activities.

`Intent i = new Intent(Page3.this, MainActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(i);`

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html, for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a flag to your intent before tarting the activity like this.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Present_Activity.this, Next_Activity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

**EDITED**

And in your main Activity before you call finish make a call to method:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: Hi Pavlos, I have tried with the snipnet code u have mentioned.The result is same.

Comment: I have added moveTaskToBack(true), But the application gets closed & comes to Home screen !!

Comment: Yeah that is supposed to happen when you finish your MainActivity! What did you expect?

Comment: Am expecting like this: When am on page2, if clicked on device back press button go to page1. Or else, if clicked on Home button(Imageview) it should go to MainActivity.class

Comment: For the imageview you have to implement its own personal on click listener. For the pages follow the intents i wrote you above. and remove the method moveTaskToBack if you dont need eventually!

Answer (score 1):

Use This code:

in the `OnClick` of Home button in all the page, write this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Page1.this,MainActivity.Class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

in `onBackPressed` of page1, write:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Page1.this,MainActivity.Class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

in `onBackPressed` of page2, write:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Page2.this,Page1.Class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

in `onBackPressed` of page3, write:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Page3.this,Page2.Class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

Comment: yeah this i have tried.. In My Case MainActivity Class communicates with server and loads JSON data. with this thing, Every time App communicates with Server that slows down the app.So, looking out for alternative solutions..

Comment: communicating with the server will make it slow for sure. Why don't you save the data in SharedPrefrences if the data is mall or in database so that you dont need to do this everytime

Answer (score 1):

Somehow i got the solution to my suitation..
On Page2, Home button SetonClickListener have written code like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Page2.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Under Manifest file:
For Main Activity have used like this

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

with this, Everytime click on Home button launches the instance MainActivity but doesnt communicate with servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) , you can use  `android:parentActivityName` attribute in manifest file while declaring any `activity`.

**Example:**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Page2"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

You don't need to start `MainActivity` using `Intent`.It will handle to call ParentActivity while executing `onBackPressed`.

If you need to add `SupportLibrary` , you can download it from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

**EDIT :**

you should manage `Activity Lifecycle` as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Inside `MainActivity`'s  `onCreate` method, initiate execution of `AsyncTask` to load data from server.

and when you move back from `Page2` , `onResume` of `MainActivity` will be called. so your data will not be loaded from Server again.

I hope it will be helpful !!